# Why this hibernate exception occurs,,,

Tags: java, hibernate, stored-procedures, hql

I'm getting the exception like,
"`Named Query mySp Not known`"

The mapping file will be looking like this,

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <sql-query name="mySp">
        <return-scalar column="count1" type="int" />
        <return-scalar column="name" type="int" />
        <return-scalar column="count2" type="int" />
        { call get_proc_sp :p1,p2,p3 }
    </sql-query>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

My Procedure name is, get_proc_sp and it accepts three parameters, the parameter names are  m1,m2,m3

This is the DAO code,

```
List<MyBean> list = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
    .getNamedQuery("mySp")
    .setParameter("m1", arg1)
    .setParameter("m2", narg)
    .setParameter("m3", arg5)
    .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(MyBean.class))
    .list();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One likely reason is that the hbm file in which you are defining the query is not registered with the sessionFactory.